# How to get two inline-block containers height to be the same when parent has height:auto

Tags: html, css

I have two `inline-block` elements. The block with the image is taller. I am wanting to match the two elements in height, so `#keyPointsBlock` needs to be the same height as `#caseSlider`.

Is there a way to do this?

```css
/*-- Slider Section --*/
#slideSec {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  min-height: 400px;
}
.slideSecBlock {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
}
/*- Key Points -*/
#keyPointsBlock {
  width: 40%;
  background: green;
  position: relative;
}
#keyPointsTitle {
  font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
  font-size: 2rem;
  letter-spacing: .2rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
#keyPointsList {
  text-decoration: none;
}
#keyPointsList li {
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}
/*- Case Slider -*/
#caseSlider {
  width: 60%;
  height: auto;
}
.caseSlide {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.caseSlide img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<section id="slideSec">
  <div class="slideSecBlock" id="keyPointsBlock">
    <div>
   <h2 id="keyPointsTitle">Key Points</h2>
     <ul id="keyPointsList">
    <li>A</li>
    <li>B</li>
    <li>C</li>
  </ul>
 </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slideSecBlock" id="caseSlider">
    <div class="caseSlide">
      <img src="https://justifiedgrid.com/wp-content/uploads/life/biking/137646854.jpg" alt="">
     </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `display: grid;` and `grid-template-columns: 40% 60%;` on #slideSec. The .slideSecBlocks don't need a width then. For the image to cover the whole div, set it as background and use `background-size: cover;`